# Filter out private members on .NET 4.5 TypeInfo.DeclaredMembers

Tags: c#, portable-class-library, system.reflection

I'm using reflection in a `PCL` project (4.5, profile 78). The reflection api has changed in 4.5 (see [Evolving the reflection API](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2012/08/28/evolving-the-reflection-api.aspx)), and event though that change is barely noticeable in the classic framework (where `TypeInfo` inherits from `Type`) it's something else for other profiles, including `PCL`.

In .NET 4, this would retrieve all the **public** members:

```
typeof(MyType).GetMembers ();
```

The rough equivalent in .NET 4.5 is

```
typeof (MyType).GetTypeInfo ().DeclaredMembers;
```

except that it returns **all** the members. The [doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.typeinfo.declaredmembers%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) says

> To filter the results of the DeclaredMembers property, use LINQ queries.

Well. I'd like to, but `MemberInfo` does not provide the `IsStatic`, `IsPrivate`, ... properties. It looks like those properties are only defined in `ConstructorInfo`, `FieldInfo`, `MethodInfo` but are missing in (base) `MemberInfo`, `PropertyInfo` and `EventInfo`.

Is there something I'm missing ? How should filter the `MemberInfo` and the `PropertyInfo`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way retrieve the accessibility accessors on `PropertyInfo` is

```
bool HasPublicGetter (PropertyInfo pi) 
{
    if (!pi.CanRead)
        return false;
    MethodInfo getter = pi.GetMethod;
    return getter.IsPublic;
}
```

Same applies to `EventInfo` with `AddMethod`.

It all make sense, as properties aren't public or private by themselves, but have public or private getters and setters.

Answer (score 0):

The GetMembers and DeclaredMembers are not the same, the DeclaredMembers ignores inherited members.
You can do the same with GetMembers using BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly like this:
GetMembers(BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static);

Comment: Please show a working example, I don't think that simply specifying `GetMembers(BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly)` will yield any results.

Comment: GetMembers(BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static);

Comment: Good! Sorry if I wasn't clear, I meant that you should update the **answer** with this information :-)